# how to get private method when i spy an object?

Tags: private, powermockito

public class A
{

```
[...]
    private int methoda(int i)
     {
        ...
        methodb();
        ....
     }
    private void methodb()
    {...}
[...]
```

}

test:

```
@Test
@PrepareForTest({...})
public void testMethoda() throws Exception
{
     //mytest
     A a = PowerMockito.spy(new A());
     Method privateMethod = a.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("methoda", int.class);
    privateMethod.setAccessible(true);

      PowerMockito.doNothing.when(a, "methodb");
     ..
}
```

with exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

who can tell me how to deal with this situation?

Comment: i have solved this problem.  Method privateMethod = A.class.getDeclaredMethod("methoda", int.class);